# Showed my CV and resume to screeners. Things are not looking good job prospect wise. How can I salvage my situation?

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-school, masters, career-path

I know I've made a couple of posts on this website by now that I've realized are me worrying and/or pure speculation. I have something now that is not in this case. I basically asked for feedback from folks who screen candidates and things are not looking good at all.

As I've gone through this job matching process given what I have now, it's looking like doing work related to academia (not that my chances were good coming out of an R2 anyway) and research (even if it's industry or federal) is out of the question based on feedback from these screeners.

Since I got autistic burnout from what little I have achieved with my Ph.D (3 page CV when I was expected to have 5 to 6 coming out) and I'm still burned out from the combination of teaching + doing my Ph.D, I might have to make a career shift after my Ph.D. I have to graduate with my Ph.D per fellowship requirements too or I need to return the $11k they awarded me.

I'm posting this update here since graduate school and the massive amount of freedom it gave was what led me (but mostly my MA and first Ph.D advisor) to putting myself in this hole right now. Some autistics who thrive in academia like that freedom since they can mess around with their special interests. I did a bit too much and that came at the expense of working on multiple projects throughout my graduate career and not pursuing collaborations or other things that were expected of me to do and I had no idea were a thing that I should've done. In other words, where I'm at now isn't much different than someone who graduates with an undergrad degree and doesn't have any internship and/or lab experience.

I'm going to try and see if I can get matched with something where I don't have much freedom responsibility wise and can have something rigid post Ph.D. That's going to be difficult since Ph.Ds are expected to work independently but I'm hoping I can manage. Does anyone know of any work like that post Ph.D?

If not, it's looking like I might have to pursue something job wise where I don't use my Ph.D. I know it won't pay well, but now that I know I haven't exactly done a Ph.D well at all, I have some relief that I can move outside of it.

Edit: My field is Experimental Psychology.

Comment: What are you referring as CV? CV and resume are the same thing in most countries... and a 3-page resume is just extremely excessive (5-6 pages is a recipe for disaster), a resume should be **at most** 2 pages, and it is highly recommended to keep it at 1 page

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I'm American so a CV and resume are two different things. A CV documents someone's entire academic catalog. My resume is 1.5 pages. It's the CV (that more positions require, including industry) that people go, "What happened here?"

Comment: Have you considered working in Europe? There are plenty of post-doc positions that you can find, and that would give you the time to think and get ready for your next step.

Comment: "3 page CV when I was expected to have 5 to 6 coming out" - whose expectation is this? I've never heard of such an expectation. If a recent PhD graduate has a 6 page CV I'd most likely assume poor formatting or padding.

Comment: Yet you managed to get a teaching position at a SLAC. So really your resume/CV is not that bad at all.

Comment: @BryanKrause This was the feedback I got from others, especially academics in industry who've screened candidates before. There was a universal reaction of "what happened?" after I sent it to them.

Comment: I think either you're getting the wrong impression, there is something in your CV besides length that is the issue, they're evaluating you for a job beyond entry-level,  or these so-called "screeners" don't know anything.

Comment: @BryanKrause The main thing is the impression I wasn't productive during my Ph.D at all (which sadly isn't wrong for reasons both in and outside of my control, but mostly the latter). A lot of them were even bold enough to question the value of my Ph.D without publications at all.

Comment: If indeed your PhD involved no publications, then that would be the issue, not the *length of your CV* measured in pages.

Comment: @BryanKrause I am the last author on a now twice rejected manuscript for journal publication as well, but that's not enough. Seems like I had the wrong impression then.

Comment: Recommend editing your field into the question (I think it is psychology), and maybe some background on these screeners (what type of positions were they screening you for?).

Comment: You essentially stated: "mostly outside my control." Honestly, you need to take responsibility for your situation. If it's due a medical or mental condition, it's because you made choices to not manage it properly. I got derailed off track with side projects which led to a lack of productivity too. And I would say that it was something I can't control, but I made the choices and take responsibility for them. It makes course correcting easier. Constantly placing the focus on external factors as to why you are in this situation essentially implies you are unable to change course. Take ownership.

Answer (score 7):

Your many questions here, including this one, indicate that you are very anxious about things, including your own abilities. I think that that anxiety is holding you back. I can't say whether it is [imposter syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome), but that is a possibility.

You say your documents have been evaluated. I hope you got good feedback on improving them. If not, I'd question the relevance of the advice you got.

Your CV, assuming you've listed all relevant things and excluded irrelevant things, is what it is. It will be evaluated against those of others in any competitive situation. But being at least somewhat self confident can be a plus in any application process in academia or elsewhere.

So, again, my suggestion is that you deal with those personal issues. If you can be more comfortable with yourself then you will be in a better position to deal with specifics. It may even be that you need a  time-out to get yourself into a better place, though I have no basis for recommending that. A good mental health professional can give proper advice, though I think I remember you saying that you do that already. You need to find ways to relax, I think.

Comment: This is good to hear. I'm likely going to speak about changing my approach to therapy but that's a "maybe" at this time. I did get advice about improving my CV but it all boiled down to "get more stuff" (there's even a question on here months ago where an answer mentioned a lack of productivity). The awakening really came into play when I spoke to someone with two Master's degrees who has an h-index of 5 and still has a hard time gaining employment related to their fields of study (Space Studies and Human Factors, Experimental Psychology) despite a near 20 page long CV coming out of Master's.

Comment: @zzmondo1 How does someone with an h-index of 5 have a 20 page CV? That sounds like a lot of uncited fluff.

Comment: @BryanKrause They do have a lot of uncited stuff when I reviewed their Google Scholar profile so you're right. They even have a book they published recently on a niche topic that rose to #1 on that category but I have no clue how meaningful that is really.